# Issue with filtering in vue-js datatable component

Tags: datatables, vuejs2

I use vue with the following datatable component:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datatable

My component is the following:

```
<template>
    <div>

        <datatable
            :columns="subsystemsTable.table_columns"
            :data="subsystems"
            filterable paginate
        ></datatable>

    </div>
</template>

<script>

    import SingleSubsystem from './SingleSubsystem.vue';


    export default {

        created() {
            this.showSubsystems();           
        },

        computed: {
            subsystems() {
                return this.$store.state.subsystemsArray;
            }
        },

        data() {
            return {
                subsystemsTable: {
                    table_columns: [
                        {label: 'id', field: 'id'},
                        {label: 'Наименование', field: 'subsystem_name'},                        
                    ]
                }                
            }
        },

        methods: {
            showSubsystems() {
                let self = this;
                this.$store.state.gatewayService.getQueryResult({
                    this: this,
                    name: 'subsystems_list',
                    actions: {
                        success: function(response) {
                            self.$store.state.subsystemsArray = response.result;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }           
        }

    }
</script>
```

But due to the fact that I use computed properties, I get the following warnings in console:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: rows.filter is not a function"

TypeError: rows.filter is not a function
    at Vue$3.filtered_rows (app.js:61503)
    at Watcher.get (app.js:54501)
    at Watcher.evaluate (app.js:54601)
    at Vue$3.computedGetter [as filtered_rows] (app.js:54855)
    at Vue$3.sorted_rows (app.js:61509)
    at Watcher.get (app.js:54501)
    at Watcher.evaluate (app.js:54601)
    at Vue$3.computedGetter [as sorted_rows] (app.js:54855)
    at Vue$3.visible_rows (app.js:61532)
    at Watcher.get (app.js:54501)
```

Anyway, everything works, but I catch these warnings. How to get rid of them.

Comment: Does your vuex state have `subsystemsArray` initialized upfront?

Comment: Thanks for tip. Actually it was initialized, but with single quotes(''), but not with  square brackets([])

Comment: you are doing `self.$store.state.subsystemsArray = response.result;` which is bad,,, use mutation to mutate(change) the state